# Book identification: time travel, own grave

Tags: story-identification, books

I realise this isn't much to go on but any suggestions?

- Paperback book
- Written *at least* 10 years ago
- The main character is a woman
- She time travels
- There's a scene where she comes upon her own grave (and the graves of her family)
- It was set in a rural location
- Quite a simple story about her life and the people she met

Comment: Maybe Connie Willis' [Doomsday Book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_Book_%28novel%29) ? Rural setting, written in 1992, iirc the time-travelling female protagonist comes upon the graves of her ancestors, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Sindi That's an impressive find but unfortunately it's not the one.

Comment: It didn't quite meet your criteria, but if you like time travel check out Willis' *To Say Nothing of the Dog*, *Doomsday Book*, and *Blackout/All Clear* series